# If $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and $\int_{P}f(z)dz \neq 0,$ Then

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose  $P$ is a covex pentagon enclosing the point $0$ in the complex plane. If $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$  and $\int_{P}f(z)dz \neq 0,$ Then

(a) $0$ is a pole or an essential singularity.

(b) $0$ is a removable singularity.

(c)$f$ has an analytic extension to $\mathbb C$

(d)$f$ has a continuous extension to $\mathbb C$

My Solution: If I take $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ condition satisfied. It has simple pole. There is no analytic extention nor continuous extension to $\mathbb C$. So, $(a)$ is the correct answer. Am I correct? But How do I prove it?

Comment: Well b, c, and d are all equivalent and any one of them would imply the integral is 0 by Cauchy’s theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singularity is not removable: if $0$ is removable, after removing it, f has an analytic extension to $\mathbb C$. Then by Cauchy integration theorem, the integral should be zero. So (b) and (c) are both wrong.

As for (d), if $f$ is made continuous at $0$, then as $\epsilon \to 0$,
$$\int_{\partial B(0,\epsilon)}f(z)dz\to0, \int_{P-\partial B(0,\epsilon)}f(z) dz=0.$$
(the 2nd equality is Cauchy integration theorem) So, 
$$\int_Pf(z)dz=\int_{\partial B(0,\epsilon)}f(z)dz+\int_{P-\partial B(0,\epsilon)}f(z)\to 0$$

So (d) is also wrong.

So we can only conclude that $0$ is a pole or an essential singularity.